# My SQL query to fetch unique records

Tags: mysql, sql

My table name is menu list, as below.

```
 Health_interest_id   menu_id
    -------------------  -------
    4                     4
    4                     10
    5                     10
    2                     4
    2                     10
    2                     15
    2                     16
    1                     4
```

Now I want result only if same recored not got before..

For example in 1st row we can see health_id=4, menu_id=4. So that row shuld be fetched,

Then in 2nd row, we can see health_id=4, which is already present in above row, so skip that row,

Same as in 3rd row, menu_id=10 which was available in above recore, so skip that, and continue for all rows. means skip if result got before.

Comment: Are you using MySQL or MS SQL Server? Don't tag products not involved.

Comment: SQL tables represent *unordered* sets.  There is no such thing as "first row" or "above", unless you specify the ordering.  Does your table have an ordering specified by values in the columns?

Comment: `Same as in 3rd row, menu_id=10 which was available in above recore, so skip that, and continue for all rows. means skip if result got before.` Since you said that second row should be skipped how we suppose to know that the third row (that will be the second) should be skipped. Please clarify your requirements.

Comment: `SELECT Health_interest_id , menu_id FROM menu GROUP BY Health_interest_id   ` You can try this code,But this will not give surety that always first record would came. Definitely it will works for 90% scenario as per your  logic.

Comment: @JorgeCampos -Yes, as you got that will be second row.. Means simply I dont want result, if specific menu or health_id found before

Comment: No, since the actual second row `4,10` will be skipped because of the first, the second row will be `5,10` therefore, as per your logic, it should be fetched BUT you are saying that it is not. Please clarify.

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm.  If you just want the distinct values in the two columns, you can do:

```
select Health_interest_id as menu_id from menulist
union
select menu_id from menulist;
```

Does this accomplish what you want?

Answer (score 0):

You really really really should move this kind of logic out of the database engine since it is not designed to do context aware selection. You are breaking the relational data concept. That being said here is a solution, which no one ever should use for any reason what so ever. I deserve to be fired and have my degrees revoked  and banned from stackoverflow just for writing it. But I think its fun to look at. Dont you dare use it ;).

```
SELECT Health_interest_id, menu_id from 
(
    SELECT 
        t2.*,
        @s:=CASE WHEN @t <> "" AND @u <> "" THEN CONCAT(@s,@t,@u) ELSE @s END,
        @t:=CASE WHEN LOCATE(CONCAT("|", Health_interest_id, "|"),@s) = 0 THEN CONCAT(Health_interest_id, "|") else "" END as AisNew,
        @u:=CASE WHEN LOCATE(CONCAT("|", menu_id, "|"),@s) = 0 THEN CONCAT(menu_id, "|") else "" END as BisNew
    FROM 
       Temp.t2 as t2,
       ( Select @s:="|" ) as s,
       ( Select @t:="" ) as t,
       ( Select @u:="" ) as u 
) AS INNER_TAB
WHERE AisNew <> "" And BisNew <> "";
```

Comment: Where is table name ?

Comment: Ive called the table Temp.t2 since I had no table name to go by.